# maven hard dependency fails build soft dependency uses same version

Tags: maven, dependencies, version, pom.xml, dependency-management

Can someone help me understand why the following happens? I want to hard-depend on jna version 4.1.0 but I think I have no choice but to hard-depend on jna version 4.3.0.

If I have "soft" dependency on jna I get this.

```
$> grep -C2 jna pom.xml 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

$> mvn dependency:tree |grep jna
[INFO] |  \- <snip>:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO] |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- <snip>:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
```

But if I change it to a hard dependency on the exact same version it is *already* using i.e. 4.1.0, I get this:

```
$> git diff
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 57a14da..52bb525 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -596,7 +596,7 @@
         <dependency>
             <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
             <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
-                <version>4.1.0</version>
+                <version>[4.1.0]</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>

$> mvn dependency:tree |grep jna
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <removed>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <removed>: Failed to collect dependencies for <snip>, net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:[4.1.0,4.1.0] <snip> No versions available for net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:[4.1.0] within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

Now if I use a hard dependency on version 4.3.0 which was released recently, it's all OK again!

```
$> git diff
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 57a14da..52bb525 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -596,7 +596,7 @@
         <dependency>
             <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
             <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
-                <version>4.1.0</version>
+                <version>[4.3.0]</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>

$> mvn dependency:tree | grep jna
[INFO] |  \- <snip>:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO] |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- <snip>:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.3.0:compile (version selected from constraint [4.3.0,4.3.0])
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.3.0:compile 
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.3.0:compile (version selected from constraint [4.3.0,4.3.0])
[INFO] |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.3.0:compile (version selected from constraint [4.3.0,4.3.0])
```

Comment: The result is strange, especially the [4.1.0,4.1.0] range ... I have no idea what is happening. But if you really want to use version 4.1.0, use <dependencyManagement> to set the version to 4.1.0 (and delete the version tag from your <dependency> entry).

Comment: Thanks @JFMeier, the above <dependency> entry is within my <dependencyManagement> section already. I have been having it as 4.1.0 all this while, and now trying to force it to be a hard dependency via [4.1.0] to prevent changes to other dependencies silently overriding my soft dependencies (via transitivity).

Comment: If you put 4.1.0 into dependencyManagement and don't overwrite it yourself (in your dependencies), then 4.1.0 is what you get. No transitive dependency can overwrite that. There is no need for putting [ ] around it.